# Regenerating a context free grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ambiguity, computation, context-free-language

I need to generate unambiguous grammar to access the language `L= { a^i b^j c^k | i, j, k ≥ 0 , i = j or i = k }`

What I already have is:

```
S : X | Y
X : TC
T : aTb | ԑ
C : cC | ԑ
Y : aYc | F
F : bF | ԑ
```

but this grammar is ambiguous, it can recognize the strings with equal number of a,b,c in two different ways. Is there any better suggestion to make it unambiguous?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this line `X : aXb | T` will result in strings of type `aaaacccbbbb` rather than `aaaabbbbccc`. Is that intentional? According to your language description it is not allowed.

Comment: Yes You are right. I fixed the line, but the grammar is still an ambiguous grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S : X | Y | Z
X : aXb | ԑ
Y : aYc | F
Z : Zc | X | ԑ
F : Fb | ԑ
```

The above has less rules and produces correct strings but I admit it's still ambiguous.

The grammar of the language L in the question can be divided into two sub-grammars producing following strings: `a^i b^i c^j` and `a^i b^j c^j` and intersection of these two will result in this kind of expressions: `a^i b^i c^i`. It can be proved that if intersection of two grammars produces this kind of expressions then the grammar is inherently ambiguous: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Inherently_ambiguous_languages

Comment: `Z` isn't referenced by any other production here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the grammar can still derive aabbcc (an equal number of a,b,c) from Y and from Z as well. means its still ambiguous.

Comment: I'll try to fix it. I popped it in first to fix the problem with incorrect strings but you already corrected it in your edit.

Comment: I think the language is inherently ambiguous, means it doesn't have un ambiguous grammar, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this topics will help you [Converting ambiguous grammar to unambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106195/converting-ambiguous-grammar-to-unambiguous)
and [Removing Ambiguity From Grammars](http://www.iitg.ernet.in/gkd/ma513/sep/sep27/note-0.pdf)